# Flycheck c/c++-clang check linux kernel headers

Tags: flycheck, linux, clang

Currently I am working with the linux kernel, but I am struggling trying to check my syntax using flycheck, I already added the path of the headers in the clang-path but it is not enough. Does any of you know how to properly analyze the files?

> This is the command run to check the syntax:

```
   clang -fsyntax-only -fno-color-diagnostics -fno-caret-diagnostics -fno-diagnostics-show-option -iquote /root/Projects/OS-Project/ -Wall -Wextra -I /lib/modules/4.11.3-1-ARCH/build/include -x c - < /root/Projects/OS-Project/main.c
```

This is an image showing where the compiler fails:
[image]

Only tags are helping me right now.